# Node.js REPL kill statement

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

```
> k.forEach( function(l) { console.log(l) }
... 
... 
... ;
... );
... )
... ;
... ]
... ,
... .
Invalid REPL keyword
... .
Invalid REPL keyword
... .
Invalid REPL keyword
... return
... ;
... break
... )
```

Is there a way to get out of that without `^D` and losing the environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure you want `.break` - it's built in along with `.help`, `.clear`, and `.exit`

Comment: COOL!!! Today I learned about `.break .clear .exit .help`, and `npm init`. It seems as if so many of my problems are solved but undocumented…

Comment: Yes. And, I always do, unfortunately you were too quick and StackOverflow has a rate throttle so the whole thing doesn't come crashing down. They built their fortress on sand.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know about the rate throttle.